# Django: Unused 'v_item.pk' at end of if expression

Tags: django, templatetags

I'm trying to hide a button if the ID already exist in other table.
I have a Confirm button in my template that i use to confirm orders and it save the confirmed orders in a table called (ConfirmOrder). So i want if order is already confirmed or the id of that order already exist in ConfirmOrder table the confirm button is disabled/hidden so that i cannot confirm it again.
I tried to use templatetags i get this error (Unused 'v_item.pk' at end of if expression)

Model

```
class ConfirmOrder(models.Model):
    order_no = models.ForeignKey(OrderDetail, related_name='confirmorders', on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(StoreStock, null=True, blank=True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2, blank=True)
    buying_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2, blank=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2, blank=True)
    confirm_note = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank=True)
    is_active = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

Template tag

```
from django import template
from ..models import ConfirmOrder

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def check_item_already_exists(request, pk):
    return ConfirmOrder.objects.filter(id=pk, is_active=1).exists()
```

Templates

```
{% for v_item in viewitem %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
    <td>{{ v_item.order_no.location }}</td>
    <td>{{ v_item.order_no.order_date }}</td>
    <td>{{ v_item.order_no.supplier }}</td>
    <td>{{ v_item.order_no.order_number }}</td>
    <td>{{ v_item.order_no.pay_ref }}</td>
    <td>{{ v_item.product }}</td>
    <td>{{ v_item.quantity }}</td>
    <td>{{ v_item.buying_price }}</td>
    <td>{{ v_item.amount }}</td>
    <td>
      {% load check_item %}
      {% if not check_item_already_exists v_item.pk %}
      <a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" href="{% url 'confirm_order' v_item.pk %}"> Confirm </a>
      {% endif %}
    </td>
```

View

```
def confirm_purchase(request):
    viewitem = OrderItem.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'managepurchase/confirmed_purchase.html', {'viewitem': viewitem})
```

Where am i doing wrong? or is there any other way i can do this?
Can any one help please!

Comment: Can you share the view that passes the `viewitem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do *not* write *business logic* in the template. A template deals with *rendering logic*. Not with *business* logic. The Django template language is *deliberately* restricted to avoid people writing a lot of business logic in the template.

In the view you can [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) the `QuerySet` with:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

def confirm_purchase(request):
    viewitem = OrderItem.objects.annotate(
        is_active=Exists(
            ConfirmOrder.objects.filter(is_active=1, pk=OuterRef('pk'))
        )
    )
    return render(request, 'managepurchase/confirmed_purchase.html', {'viewitem': viewitem})
```

then in the template we can render it with:

```
{% if v_item.is_active %}
    <a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" href="{% url 'confirm_order' v_item.pk %}"> Confirm </a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: So, i should not use template tag?

Comment: @EricksonKitoz: no, but why would you here use a template tag. Based on its implementation, it is just `v_item.is_active` (except that you make an extra query, which will make it rather slow). If you need more complicated things, it is better to move these to the view layer.

Comment: Actualy I'm new in django, im trying get a better way of doing it. i'll try your way. Thanks

Comment: If is use v_item.is_active do i have to create a view?

Comment: @EricksonKitoz: no, since it just a field of the model, you can simply write `{% if v_item.is_active %}` here.

Comment: I use v_item.is_active and now my buttons are all hidden

Comment: but it's not belong to that model

Comment: @EricksonKitoz: how does `OrderItem` related to `ConfirmOrder`?

Comment: @EricksonKitoz: it is a bit *odd* that these somehow share the same primary key.

Comment: They're not related, i didn't use foreign key

Comment: @EricksonKitoz: but then the primary key is the same? How will you ensure/enforce this?

Comment: No the primary key is not the same, ConfirmOrder is a defferent model it has no relation to OrderItem

Comment: What should i do?

Comment: @EricksonKitoz: but in your template tag, you write `return ConfirmOrder.objects.filter(id=pk, is_active=1).exists()`, so here you check if a `ConfirmOrder` has the same pk as the pk of the `OrderItem`. We can check that with annotations (see edited answer). But it looks a bit *risky* to assume that the pks will be in sync. If you later scale your app for example on different servers, it will be (close) to impossible to guarantee such things.

Comment: But you say its bit a risky why?

Comment: @EricksonKitoz: the fact that you let the two models share the "primary key space" is risky. So you might want to remodel this with a `ForeignKey`.

Comment: Ok, if i use foreign key, do i have to change the code in my view?

Comment: @EricksonKitoz: yes, then it should be `ConfirmOrder.objects.filter(is_active=1, name_of_foreignkey=OuterRef('pk'))` in the view.

Comment: Okay, i'll do that

Comment: Thank you so much Willem. I appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

Your line

```
{% if not check_item_already_exists v_item.pk %}
```

contains 2 parts (`check_item_already_exists` and `v_item.pk`) for the condition, but only one part is allowed.

You cannot pass arguments to a function call inside Django templates (that is a design decision in Django), so you will have to find another way to get the info you need in the template, maybe by calling the function in the view instead of in the template.